# NestJS: Using injected service inside @Module

Tags: dependency-injection, module, nestjs, config, decorator

I'm not particular familiar with NestJS's Modules framework, so I need some help with the problem below.

I'm using NestJs [Config feature](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration). It works fine in my TypeORM config file, because I just needed to inject it into the TypeORM config service and use it.

But now I want to use the config service inside a `@Module` decorator, as shown below:

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { UsuarioModule } from '@api/usuario/usuario.module';
import { LocalStrategy } from './strategies';
import { AuthenticationController } from './authentication.controller';
import { AuthenticationService } from './authentication.service';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

@Module({
  imports: [
    PassportModule,
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: this.configService.get<string>('JWT_SECRET'),
      signOptions: {
        expiresIn: this.configService.get<string>('JWT_EXPIRES_IN') ?? '1h',
      },
    }),
    UsuarioModule,
  ],
  providers: [AuthenticationService, LocalStrategy],
  controllers: [AuthenticationController],
  exports: [AuthenticationService],
})
export class AuthenticationModule {
  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {}
}
```

Is there any way I can work around this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After some more research I came across this solution:

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { UsuarioModule } from '@api/usuario/usuario.module';
import { LocalStrategy } from './strategies';
import { AuthenticationController } from './authentication.controller';
import { AuthenticationService } from './authentication.service';

@Module({
  imports: [
    PassportModule,
    JwtModule.registerAsync({
      useFactory: async () => ({
        secretOrPrivateKey: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
        signOptions: {
          expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN ?? '1h',
        },
      }),
    }),
    UsuarioModule,
  ],
  providers: [AuthenticationService, LocalStrategy],
  controllers: [AuthenticationController],
  exports: [AuthenticationService],
})
export class AuthenticationModule {}
```